# runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I need to create a dialog with jQuery in a pretty big project. In some places, this project uses jquery wich version is different from the one I use recent for my window.

My code looks like this:

on ascx page

```
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myjQueryCode.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

in myjQueryCode.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 440,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false
    });
});
```

At runtime, I get the error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or
>   method 'dialog'

Comment: Are you sure the custom jQuery UI files holds the dialog module? What happens if you include the full UI file?

Comment: Are you referring <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> in master page and/or context page as well

Comment: I saw the jQuery UI is custom version, so did you include the `dialog`?

Comment: Jonas G. Drange, yes, I'm sure. In the separate project it works well. Could you tell me, where can I find the full UI file?

Comment: KSaini, <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> is only in the content (ascx) page.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answers. The problem was that the library was included multiple times in different files.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog method is from the jQuery UI library.  It looks like you are using a custom version of jQuery UI, which *may* not include dialog.

You can customize which modules to include in jQuery UI here: http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: When I use this code in a separate asp.net project, it works well.

Comment: Does the other project use the same jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js file?

Comment: You can download the full jQuery UI library at the link in the answer, or Google can host it for you: <script type="text/javacsript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js">

Comment: Yes, the file in the other project is exactly the same. Thank you for the link, but when I include it, result is the same error.

Comment: Could it be some kind of conflict in jQuery files?

Answer (score 1):

View the page's HTML to see if there are script references to other versions of jquery in the page. If an older version is loaded after the correct version then invalid methods will throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the above fails, try:

Check your packages installed - I resolved this issue by Installing Nuget Package: JQuery.Draggable - See: http://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.UI.Interactions.Draggable/